# How does Weierstrass' theorem follow from Mergelyan's theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis, approximation-theory, weierstrass-approximation

According to Theorems 1 and 3 in [this review article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.03924.pdf) we have

> **Weierstrass:** Suppose $f$ is a continuous function on a closed bounded interval $[a,b] \subset\mathbb{R}$. For every $\epsilon > 0$
>   there exists a polynomial $p$ such that for all $x \in [a,b]$ we have
>   $| f(x)− p(x)| < \epsilon$.
>
> **Mergelyan:** If $K$ is a compact set in $C$ with connected complement, then every continuous function $f\colon K\to \mathbb{C}$
>   that is holomorphic in the interior of $K$ can be approximated
>   uniformly on $K$ by holomorphic polynomials.

Both [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mergelyan%27s_theorem) and the [review](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.03924.pdf) say that the latter is a generalization of the former. In which sense is this true? 
How does Weierstrass' theorem follow from Mergelyan's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The hypotheses of Weierstrass satisfy the hypotheses of Mergelyan:

$K=[a,b] \subseteq \mathbb C$ is a compact set with connected complement.

Since $K$ has empty interior, "holomorphic in the interior of $K$" is true.

> The conclusions of Mergelyan imply the conclusions of Weierstrass:

"approximated uniformly" is the same as "$| f(x)− p(x)| < \epsilon$ for all $x \in K$".

Comment: The issue is that those approximation polynomials are complex. To complete the argument, you might consider their real part.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net, ah, I see, that's an important point, thanks.

Comment: Oh how embarassing. I somehow thought the interior of $K$ needed to be nonempty and thought that somehow the function from the Weierstrass theorem would need to be thought of as a function on a part of the boundary of a unit disk etc.